# Running into issue using Google login with Expo Auth Session

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm getting this error the first time I open the app and I call the sign in function. It works the second time though.

> Cannot prompt to authenticate until the request has finished loading.

Here is my code for Google login:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext, useMemo } from "react"
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google"
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser"
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential, auth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "../firebase"

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession()

const config = {
  expoClientId: xxxx
  webClientId: xxxx
  iosClientId: xxxx
  androidClientId: xxxx
}

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user,setUser] = useState(null)
  const [error,setError] = useState(null)
  const [req, res, login] = Google.useAuthRequest(config)

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  useEffect(
    () =>
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
        setLoading(true)
        if (user) {
          setUser(user)
          setLoading(false)
        } else {
          setUser(null)
        }
        setLoading(false)
      }),
    []
  )
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    login({ showInRecents: true })
      .then(async response => {
        if (response && response.type === "success") {
          const { accessToken, idToken } = response.authentication
          const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken)
          await signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
          setLoading(false)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }
```

Not really sure whats going on, but it works on a second click. My firebase isn't connecting by default either. If sign in and then refresh the app, I don't get user information by default.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find out how to use the google useAuthRequest from a contextprovider?

If i copy all the code into the login component it works fine, but I don't want my auth code to be all over the place. Better to have it all in the same provider.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, right after i commented i found the suggestion on another stackoverflow topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213137/request-not-being-completed-with-expo-authsession).

So in your case the solution would be to replace the anonymous "signInWithGoogle " function with a callback and add the promptasync to the dependency.

If you want to export the promptAsync from the contextprovider, you can use a useMemo and add the promptAsync to that dependency.